# Fancy Box does not work on heroku

Tags: heroku, fancybox, lightbox

I am working on a rails app and I am using fancybox-rails as my image lightbox. It works perfectly in development but when I push it to Heroku it does not work. I tried viewing the compiled application.js for any present of 'fancybox' but none. Clicking on a thumbnail just opens the bigger image on the browser and navigates away.

What could I have missed

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'fancybox-rails'
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require fancybox
//= require_tree .
```

**application.css**

```
 *= require_self
 *= require fancybox
 *= require_tree .
```

**coffescript file**

```
(($) ->
  $(document).ready ->
    $("a.fancybox").fancybox
      transitionIn: "elastic"
      transitionOut: "elastic"
) jQuery
```

### **HTML page**

```
<%= link_to( image_tag( @logo.photo.url(:small), title: "Click to enlarge"), @logo.photo.url, class: 'fancybox') %>
```

---

This works perfectly on development but nothing happens in production. Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run the following before pushing to heroku:

```
rake assets:precompile
```